# Preload associations with an existing scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, eager-loading

I wrote a piece of code to eager load some associations from an already loaded collection:

```
@articles= Article.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE blabla")    
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(@articles, {:comments => {:user => :permissions}}).run
```

I have a scope defined in my Article class ready to eager load some articles associations at several levels:

```
class Article << ActiveRecord::Base
  [...]      

  scope :eager_loading_for_comments, includes(:comments => {:user => :permissions})
end
```

Am I able to use this scope in my first code ? A way like that:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(@articles, :eager_loading_for_comments).run
```

Or:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(@articles, Article.eager_loading_for_comments).run
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call the scope as you would any other, e.g.

```
@articles = Article.eager_loading_for_comments
```

?

Comment: nope, my problematic (not exposed here, too complicated. Quickly, it is a huge query with many joins to tables not involved in the scope) forces me to to a find_by_sql so I cannot use the scope directly with this classic way.

Answer (score 0):

How about chaining the where onto the scope:

```
Article.eager_loading_for_comments.where("blah blah blah")
```

Comment: nope, my problematic (not exposed here, too complicated. Quickly, it is a huge query with many joins to tables not involved in the scope) forces me to to a find_by_sql so I cannot use the scope directly with this classic way.